# Showing that an arithmetic function is multiplicative

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Let $f$ be an arithmetic function that counts the number of consecutive integers between $1$ and $n$ (inclusive) such that both integers are coprime to $n$. More formally,

$$ f(n) = \sum_{\substack{1 \leq t \leq n \\ (t,n)=1 \\ (t+1,n)=1}}1. $$

An immediate observation is that $f(n)=0$ when $n$ is even. After playing around with this function, I suspect that it is multiplicative. That is, if $(a,b)=1$, then $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$. However, I am unable to prove this.

Is this function really multiplicative or are there counterexamples?

Also, what happens when we modify $f$ so that it counts the number of consecutive triplets that are all coprime to $n$?

Comment: So for $f(15)$ it counts $1,7,13$ because $2,8,14$ are also coprime to $15$ and so $f(15)=3$?

Comment: Yes. $f(5)=3$ since $(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)$ are all the pairs both coprime to $5$ and $f(3)=1$ since $(1,2)$ is the only such pair. As a matter of fact, we can say that $f(p)=p-2$ when $p$ is a prime since every pair other than $(p-1, p)$ and $(p,p+1)$ will be counted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $\gcd(m,n)=1$

Then let $(i,i+1)$  be a good pair for $m$ and let $(j,j+1)$ be a good pair for $n$.  The Chinese Remainder theorem gives us a unique  $k$ with $1≤k≤mn-1$ such that $$k\equiv i\pmod m\quad \&\quad k\equiv j \pmod n$$

Clearly we have
$$k+1\equiv i+1\pmod m\quad \&\quad k+1\equiv j+1 \pmod n$$

So $(k,k+1)$ is a good pair for $mn$.

It remains to be shown that every good pair for $mn$ arises this way.  But if $(k,k+1)$ is  a good pair for $mn$ then remark that $tm<k<\left((t+1)m-1\right)$ for some $t$ so $(k\pmod m,(k+1)\pmod m)$ is a good pair for $m$ (and similarly for $n$) and we are done.

Answer (score 4):

Let $m$ and $n$ be coprime positive integers. [Chinese reminder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) gives us a ring isomorphism

$$
g: \mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \\
x\pmod{mn} \mapsto (x\pmod m, x\pmod n).
$$

For integer $k$, define $A_k \subset \mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ as

$$
A_k = \{t \in \mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z} \, | \, \gcd(t, k) = 1 \land \gcd(t + 1, k) = 1\}.
$$

Note that $x \in A_k$ if and only if both $x$ and $x + 1$ are units in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ i.e. $x \in A_k$ if and only if there exist $y \in \mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ and $z \in \mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$
xy = 1 \pmod k \\
(x + 1)z = 1 \pmod k.
$$

Since $g$ preserves inverses, we see that  $t \in A_{mn}$ if and only if $g(t) = (t_1, t_2)$ with $t_1 \in A_m$ and $t_2 \in A_n$. Thus, $g$ restricted to $A_{mn}$ is a bijection between $A_{mn}$ and $A_m \times A_n$. Therefore, $|A_{mn}| = |A_m| |A_n|$.

Multiplicativity of $f$ follows since $f(k) = |A_k|$.

---

Using the result above and the observation that $f(p^k) = p^{k-1}(p - 2)$ for prime $p$, one can derive a formula for $f(n)$ where $n = p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\dots p_r^{k_r}$

$$
f(n) = \prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{k_i-1} (p_i - 2) = n \prod_{i=1}^r \left(1 - \frac{2}{p_i}\right)
$$

which is reminiscent of a similar formula for the [Euler totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

We can restrict to values $(a,b)$ such that $a,b>2$ are odd and coprime.
Now we use the following observations:

- $f(n)$ counts the number of points $(x,y)$ with coordinates in the ring $\Bbb Z/n$ such that
  $$
  \tag{$C(n)$}
  x(x+1)y=1\ .
  $$
- If $u,v$ are invertible modulo $n$, then we can use alternatively (set e.g. $x=ux'$, etc.)
  $$
  \tag{$C(n;u,v)$}
  x(x+u)y=v\ .
  $$
- $\Bbb Z/ab\cong (\Bbb Z/a)\times(\Bbb Z/b)$, $x\cong(x',x'')$ in the category of rings. (Chinese Remainder Theorem, CRT.)
- We need an explicit isomorphism. So we write $1=as+bt$ in $\Bbb Z/ab$, where $(a,b)=(s,b)=(t,a)=(s,t)=1$.
- The explicit ring isomorphism from the CRT is $(x',x'')\to x:=btx'+asx''$. (So $(1',1'')\to 1$.) The converse morphism is the canonical projection.
- Let $(x,y)$ be a solution modulo $ab$. Then with $x=btx'+asx''$ we have
  $$
  1=x(x+1)y=(btx'+asx'')(btx'+asx''+as+bt)y\ ,
  $$
  and reading this modulo $a$, respectively modulo $b$ we obtain solutions in $\Bbb Z/a$ and $\Bbb Z/b$ for the equations $C(a;1,1/(bt)^2=1)$ and $C(b; 1, 1/(as)^2=1)$.
- Conversely, let us start with a solution $(x', ?')$ modulo $a$, and a solution $(x'',?'')$ modulo $b$ for the equations above, the corresponding $x$ leads to a solution modulo $ab$.

$\square$

---

*Note:* Since for a prime $p$ we have $f(p^k)=(p-2)p^{k-1}$, we have in general for a number $N$ with prime factor decomposition
$$
N=p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\dots p_r^{k_r} 
$$
the formula
$$
f(N)
=N
\left(1-\frac 2{p_1}\right)
\left(1-\frac 2{p_2}\right)
\cdots
\left(1-\frac 2{p_r}\right)
\ .
$$